# Switched objective-C app to x86_64 and sizeof is returning the wrong result

Tags: objective-c, c, sizeof

So I have a struct that I generally just do sizeof(mystruct) and it would return 0x2C when compiled for x86, but as soon as I switched the compiler over to JUST x86_64 it's telling me the size is 0x30 which makes no sense to me.

Here is the struct:

```
typedef struct Struct
{
    int32_t unk1;       // 0x0
    int32_t unk2;       // 0x4
    int32_t unk3;       // 0x8
    int32_t unk4;       // 0xC

    int64_t    guid;       // 0x10
    int32_t  entryID;   // 0x18
    int32_t  bytes;     // 0x1C
    int32_t  duration;  // 0x20
    int32_t  expiration;   // 0x24

    int32_t  unk5;      // 0x28
} Struct;
```

I then do:

```
Struct mystruct;
NSLog(@"0x%X", sizeof(mystruct));
```

And it's printing out 0x30, but shouldn't it be 0x2C? I don't see where my problem is

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's [structure padding](https://www.google.com/search?q=struct+padding+site%3Astackoverflow.com) to ensure that arrays of your type are properly aligned for your architecture.  If you have an array:

```
Struct myarray[2];
```

Then each element needs to be 4-byte aligned on x86 but 8-byte aligned on x86-64.  In order to guarantee that, the total structure size must be a multiple of 8 bytes, so the compiler adds extra padding at the end.